# Dart TypeSafe - List and Iterable

Tags: dart

In the following code , bar is a `List` but right side is a `WhereIterable`, As dart is a type safe language I have expected to have an error in **Build time**, but I have `Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'WhereIterable<int>': type 'WhereIterable<int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'` error in **Run time**

```dart
void main() {
  final List<int> foo = [1, 2, 3];
  final List<int> bar = foo.where((e) => e > 1);
}
```

I know that adding `.toList()` fix error, My question is : Why we have no error in **Compile/Build time**?

Comment: Have a look here https://codewithandrea.com/articles/2020-06-22-implicit-downcast-no-longer-allowed/ , since dart 2.9  implicit downcasts are no longer allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because dart implicitly casts **Iterable** to **List**. This is default behavior. In order to disable this one should turn of implicit casts in analyzer settings like this:

```yaml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

More information can be found here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks and here:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system

Comment: Can you explain more? Why?

Comment: If it  implicitly casts Iterable to List, Why we have runtime error ?

Comment: Because implicit cast work only on analysis (compile) time. It makes you responsible to decide whether Iterable that is coming out from "where" is indeed list. When you run program, it turns out that  "where" returns WhereIterable<int>, not List, thus you have runtime error.